# nginx working with my ip but not my domain name

Tags: nginx

I deployed my Django app on my VPS configured with Nginx. When I try to access through IP it is ok but when I want to access through domain name I face with gateway timeout and the connection does not establish.
I am sure that my domain is truly connected to my IP and the problem is with Nginx
in /etc/Nginx/sites-available I created two files. one for my IP and the other one for my domain

file name: 188.121.123.141

```
 server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name 188.121.123.141 www.188.121.123.141 https://parizaan.ir www.parizaan.com;
    root /var/www/188.121.123.141;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

file name : parizaan.ir

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name parizaan.ir www.parizaan.ir;
    root /var/www/parizaan.ir;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ host parizaan.com
Host parizaan.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Your domain is not configured properly.

nginx.conf:

```
<...>
server_name 188.121.123.141 www.188.121.123.141 https://parizaan.com www.parizaan.com;
```

`www.188.121.123.141`, `https://parizaan.com` entries are bad.

so, looks like nor you nginx is configured properly, nor dns.

Comment: sorry the domain has changed to parizaan.ir it was my mistake . but I changed them and it is still not working. also 188.121.123.141 is accessible

Comment: Is ip address correct? `parizaan.ir has address 185.143.233.120, 185.143.234.120`. Still looks as dns misconfiguration.

Comment: my VPS is on a cloud provider and I added my domain there so when I request to domain first it will go to cloud provider and after that it redirects to my VPS ip